# Get maximum for each group based on time condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have this dataframe `df`

```
   id        date     time  record
0   1  2021-07-08  3:00:00       8
1   1  2021-07-08  5:30:00       7
2   1  2021-07-08  9:00:00      10
3   1  2021-01-08  6:30:00       5
4   1  2021-01-08  9:30:00       7
5   2  2021-07-08  3:00:00       7
6   2  2021-07-08  9:00:00      14
7   2  2021-07-08  5:30:00      10
8   2  2021-01-08  3:00:00      11
9   2  2021-01-08  3:00:00      13
```

I need to create a new column `max` equal to the maximum grouped by `id` and `date`. But also I need to get maximum value only if `time` is earlier than 7:00:00. I.e for `id=1` and `date=2021-07-08` `max` columns should be equal to 8, not 10, because we got 10 when `time` was 9:00:00.

Here's the dataframe `df` in a more accessible way

```
import io
import pandas as pd

data1_txt = """
id,date,time,record
1,2021-07-08,3:00:00,8
1,2021-07-08,5:30:00,7
1,2021-07-08,9:00:00,10
1,2021-01-08,6:30:00,5
1,2021-01-08,9:30:00,7
2,2021-07-08,3:00:00,7
2,2021-07-08,9:00:00,14
2,2021-07-08,5:30:00,10
2,2021-01-08,3:00:00,11
2,2021-01-08,3:00:00,13
"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data1_txt))
```

The desirable result is

```
   id        date     time  record  max
0   1  2021-07-08  3:00:00       8    8
1   1  2021-07-08  5:30:00       7    8
2   1  2021-07-08  9:00:00      10    8
3   1  2021-01-08  6:30:00       5    5
4   1  2021-01-08  9:30:00       7    5
5   2  2021-07-08  3:00:00       7   10
6   2  2021-07-08  9:00:00      14   10
7   2  2021-07-08  5:30:00      10   10
8   2  2021-01-08  3:00:00      11   13
9   2  2021-01-08  3:00:00      13   13
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us do in steps

- Extract the hours component from the time column
- Compare the hours component with `7` to create a boolean mask
- Mask the values in `record` column where hour is greater than `7`
- `Group` the masked column by `id` and `date` and `transform` using `max` to calculate the maximum value per group

```
m = pd.to_timedelta(df['time']).dt.components['hours'].ge(7)
df['max'] = df['record'].mask(m).groupby([df['id'], df['date']]).transform('max')
```

---

```
   id        date     time  record   max
0   1  2021-07-08  3:00:00       8   8.0
1   1  2021-07-08  5:30:00       7   8.0
2   1  2021-07-08  9:00:00      10   8.0
3   1  2021-01-08  6:30:00       5   5.0
4   1  2021-01-08  9:30:00       7   5.0
5   2  2021-07-08  3:00:00       7  10.0
6   2  2021-07-08  9:00:00      14  10.0
7   2  2021-07-08  5:30:00      10  10.0
8   2  2021-01-08  3:00:00      11  13.0
9   2  2021-01-08  3:00:00      13  13.0
```

Comment: Just a last question, what if I would like to change the time limit from 7:00:00 to 7:15:00, what should I do. I.e. i also need minute component

Comment: @BogdanTitomir In that case we can directly compare the timedelta objects with the time string for e.g. you could do `m = pd.to_timedelta(df['time'])  >= '07:15:00'`

Answer (score 1):

Let's make sure that time is datatime type:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
```

Filter times before 7:00, group and apply transform:

```
s = df.loc[(df['time'] < '7:00')].groupby(['id', 'date'])['record'].transform('max').rename('max')
```

Merge result and fill forward:

```
df2 = pd.concat([df, s], axis=1)
df2['max'] = df2['max'].ffill().astype(int)
```

output:

```
   id       date                time  record  max
0   1 2021-07-08 2021-07-08 03:00:00       8    8
1   1 2021-07-08 2021-07-08 05:30:00       7    8
2   1 2021-07-08 2021-07-08 09:00:00      10    8
3   1 2021-01-08 2021-07-08 06:30:00       5    5
4   1 2021-01-08 2021-07-08 09:30:00       7    5
5   2 2021-07-08 2021-07-08 03:00:00       7   10
6   2 2021-07-08 2021-07-08 09:00:00      14   10
7   2 2021-07-08 2021-07-08 05:30:00      10   10
8   2 2021-01-08 2021-07-08 03:00:00      11   13
9   2 2021-01-08 2021-07-08 03:00:00      13   13
```